# Getting langchain agent_scratchpad input error

Tags: python, agent, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

```
from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

from langchain.agents import Tool, AgentExecutor, initialize_agent, AgentType, Agent
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

from langchain.agents.chat.base import ChatAgent

tools = [    
]

callback_manager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])

llm = LlamaCpp(
                model_path="llama-2-7b-chat.Q4_K_M.gguf",
                input={"temperature": 0.75,
                       "max_length": 5000,
                       "top_p": 0.1},
                callback_manager=callback_manager,
                verbose=True
                )


prefix = """
You are a chatbot having a conversation with a human. Only respond to the user's input. 
"""

suffix = """

{chat_history}

{agent_scratchpad}

User: {input}
Chatbot: 

"""
#ai_prefix = """"""
#human_prefix = """"""




memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

prompt = ChatAgent.create_prompt(
            tools, 
            system_message_prefix=prefix, 
            system_message_suffix=suffix, 
            input_variables=["input", "chat_history", "agent_scratchpad"]
        )



llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt, memory=memory)

agent = ChatAgent(
    llm_chain=llm_chain, 
    tools=tools, 
    verbose=True,
    prompt=prompt,
)


agent_executor = AgentExecutor.from_agent_and_tools(
            agent=agent, 
            tools=tools, 
            memory=memory,
            verbose = True
            )


resp = agent_executor.run(input = "Hi")
```

This is my code. The tools will be added later. I want to create a single conversational agent capable of remembering conversation content with langchain. However, when I use this code,

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...



System: Hello! What's up? 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 1
----> 1 resp = agent_executor.run(input = "Hi")

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:492, in Chain.run(self, callbacks, tags, metadata, *args, **kwargs)
    487     return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
    488         _output_key
    489     ]
    491 if kwargs and not args:
--> 492     return self(kwargs, callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
    493         _output_key
    494     ]
    496 if not kwargs and not args:
    497     raise ValueError(
    498         "`run` supported with either positional arguments or keyword arguments,"
    499         " but none were provided."
    500     )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:292, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
    290 except BaseException as e:
    291     run_manager.on_chain_error(e)
--> 292     raise e
    293 run_manager.on_chain_end(outputs)
    294 final_outputs: Dict[str, Any] = self.prep_outputs(
    295     inputs, outputs, return_only_outputs
    296 )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:286, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
    279 run_manager = callback_manager.on_chain_start(
    280     dumpd(self),
    281     inputs,
    282     name=run_name,
    283 )
    284 try:
    285     outputs = (
--> 286         self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
    287         if new_arg_supported
    288         else self._call(inputs)
    289     )
    290 except BaseException as e:
    291     run_manager.on_chain_error(e)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py:1122, in AgentExecutor._call(self, inputs, run_manager)
   1120 # We now enter the agent loop (until it returns something).
   1121 while self._should_continue(iterations, time_elapsed):
-> 1122     next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
   1123         name_to_tool_map,
   1124         color_mapping,
   1125         inputs,
   1126         intermediate_steps,
   1127         run_manager=run_manager,
   1128     )
   1129     if isinstance(next_step_output, AgentFinish):
   1130         return self._return(
   1131             next_step_output, intermediate_steps, run_manager=run_manager
   1132         )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py:919, in AgentExecutor._take_next_step(self, name_to_tool_map, color_mapping, inputs, intermediate_steps, run_manager)
    916     intermediate_steps = self._prepare_intermediate_steps(intermediate_steps)
    918     # Call the LLM to see what to do.
--> 919     output = self.agent.plan(
    920         intermediate_steps,
    921         callbacks=run_manager.get_child() if run_manager else None,
    922         **inputs,
    923     )
    924 except OutputParserException as e:
    925     if isinstance(self.handle_parsing_errors, bool):

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\agent.py:531, in Agent.plan(self, intermediate_steps, callbacks, **kwargs)
    519 """Given input, decided what to do.
    520 
    521 Args:
   (...)
    528     Action specifying what tool to use.
    529 """
    530 full_inputs = self.get_full_inputs(intermediate_steps, **kwargs)
--> 531 full_output = self.llm_chain.predict(callbacks=callbacks, **full_inputs)
    532 return self.output_parser.parse(full_output)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\llm.py:257, in LLMChain.predict(self, callbacks, **kwargs)
    242 def predict(self, callbacks: Callbacks = None, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    243     """Format prompt with kwargs and pass to LLM.
    244 
    245     Args:
   (...)
    255             completion = llm.predict(adjective="funny")
    256     """
--> 257     return self(kwargs, callbacks=callbacks)[self.output_key]

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:294, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, run_name, include_run_info)
    292     raise e
    293 run_manager.on_chain_end(outputs)
--> 294 final_outputs: Dict[str, Any] = self.prep_outputs(
    295     inputs, outputs, return_only_outputs
    296 )
    297 if include_run_info:
    298     final_outputs[RUN_KEY] = RunInfo(run_id=run_manager.run_id)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\base.py:390, in Chain.prep_outputs(self, inputs, outputs, return_only_outputs)
    388 self._validate_outputs(outputs)
    389 if self.memory is not None:
--> 390     self.memory.save_context(inputs, outputs)
    391 if return_only_outputs:
    392     return outputs

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\memory\chat_memory.py:35, in BaseChatMemory.save_context(self, inputs, outputs)
     33 def save_context(self, inputs: Dict[str, Any], outputs: Dict[str, str]) -> None:
     34     """Save context from this conversation to buffer."""
---> 35     input_str, output_str = self._get_input_output(inputs, outputs)
     36     self.chat_memory.add_user_message(input_str)
     37     self.chat_memory.add_ai_message(output_str)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\memory\chat_memory.py:22, in BaseChatMemory._get_input_output(self, inputs, outputs)
     18 def _get_input_output(
     19     self, inputs: Dict[str, Any], outputs: Dict[str, str]
     20 ) -> Tuple[str, str]:
     21     if self.input_key is None:
---> 22         prompt_input_key = get_prompt_input_key(inputs, self.memory_variables)
     23     else:
     24         prompt_input_key = self.input_key

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain\memory\utils.py:19, in get_prompt_input_key(inputs, memory_variables)
     17 prompt_input_keys = list(set(inputs).difference(memory_variables + ["stop"]))
     18 if len(prompt_input_keys) != 1:
---> 19     raise ValueError(f"One input key expected got {prompt_input_keys}")
     20 return prompt_input_keys[0]

ValueError: One input key expected got ['agent_scratchpad', 'input']
```

It shows this error. I also tried removing the 'agent_scratchpad', but I encountered another error indicating it is an essential component.

How should I bring in the 'agent_scratchpad'?

I also tried removing the 'agent_scratchpad', but I encountered another error indicating it is an essential component.

I tried changing the order of input_variables and also experimented with different suffix prompts.

And the ZeroshotAgent didn't encounter this error.